# Unity3D collision strange behaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Something must be wrong with this code because I put Debug.Log into the collision first to make sure it worked and it worked perfectly. The problem is that the score acts irregularly, sometimes increasing by 20, sometimes decreasing by 20, and sometimes staying the same. I must be making some stupid mistake that I can't see.

```
public int score = 0;

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.name == "Plane")
    {
//On collision, add 10 to score, access text, change text to score. 
score += 10;
    TextMesh ScoreMesh = GameObject.Find("Score").GetComponent<TextMesh>();
        ScoreMesh.text = score.ToString ();
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, `ScoreMesh` should be lowercase as it is a variable, not a public field/property. 

Second, you can confirm that score is always at the correct value? Can you try commenting out the last two lines of the `if` statement to see the behavior change? Is this being called twice per frame? (Use `Debug.Log`)

Comment: I commented out the last 2 lines and switched for a debug like you suggested. The score is going up and down. Each time it collides with the plane it recognizes more than one collision that is the problem. I wonder how I fix that? I must be because the object is resting on the plane after collision?

Comment: No, that can't be the problem, because this when the collision enters, so it should only fire once. Is this script attached to any other `gameObject`? Is there any bouncing when `this` enters? And does it always fire exactly twice? If so, you can always use a work around of making the score increase by 5, but that doesn't really _solve_ the problem, and might cause more in the future.

Comment: So you are staying that even if it collides and stays attached for a period of time, this would only count as one collision? There is no bouncing or any other game objects that shouldn't be there. It fires in a loop btw

Comment: In all of this, I still have no idea how it could be moving by increments of 20. That is probably a key diagnostic feature here.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "it fires in a loop"? Do you mean it is firing in a for-loop, or while-loop, etc, or it is firing a set amount of times? How many times is it firing?

Comment: Its firing at random intervals within set parameters, and it does this over and over again on a queue. And I've pinpointed the problem which is that for expected collision, it registers 2 collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Is score+=10 like that in the code you run? If so, it needs to be in the if statement. Then you need to make the scoremesh a variable, right now you have two types, `TextMesh` and `ScoreMesh`, and no variable, so make it one type and a variable. You would then replace `ScoreMesh.text` with `whatever.text`

Comment: += 10 is in the if statement? I understand, make scoremesh a variable. I will try that now

Comment: I was asking if the line score += 10 is inside the if statment (indented), if it's not it should be. Then I would be most concerned about the line: TextMesh ScoreMesh, ScoreMesh is a type, so if you want to keep that name, make it lowercase or somethig to indicate its a variable.

Comment: So I declared it scoremesh a variable within the if statement is that ok? The type is TextMesh and the variable is scoremesh

Comment: It depends how you did it, you'll have to show me. What I meant with the score += 10 being inside the if statement is that the code has to be indented to match the code inside the if statement, if it is indented like the way it shows above, its not inside the if statement.

Comment: So I have figured out that all of that stuff is set up fine. The problem is that I am registering multiple collisions where I only want 1 because the GameObject is resting on the other GameObject for a period of time it kicks again for the next collision. I have to figure out a way to limit this to one collision per kick.

Comment: If it works, make it a Trigger and update the code to OnTriggerEnter. That way it fires once when there's a collision.

Comment: Right that would get rid of any funny business that might happen with collisions if there is bouncing, etc. I will try that quick and report back. Good idea.

Comment: I'm not getting any feedback at all from a trigger. I will keep playing with it here for a minute

Comment: Yeah the collider works wrong but the trigger won't get my any data at all. I will have to investigate what might cause this and then maybe find an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98753/discussion-between-jonnydoeinwisco-and-manbearpig1).